# Without reloading Tableview, update the changed index cell values using Observer in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, watch, observers

In the first time I collect the array values from API response and displayed it in tableview, again I will get the same response from socket and reload the values in table, But here I don't need to reload entire table, I want update the cell's which value has been changed.

Here Compare the two array's, from which index has changes, just need to update that index row cells only, without reload entire table view.[old and new array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWsXu.png), [CodeSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elxSR.png)

Comment: This is the function you need: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows

Comment: Thanks for your reference link, from this I will update the particular cell.
But I need to watch an old array compare with new array which index has been changed, from this only I will find the indexpath, How can I handle this.

Comment: When you say watch an array, I believe it is being updated from the API. I suggest you add some code to your question to show how the array is getting data from the API and give some examples of what you mean is different ? From there one of use can guide you.

Comment: Old and New array https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWsXu.png

Answer (score 0):

But you should be careful if will change some indexPaths in you data stack, if it gonna happen - use `tableView.deleteRows` or `tableView.deleteSections`. This updates should be qual in table and in dataStack or `crash`

```
let indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
tableView.performBatchUpdates {
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
}
```

or

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

btw, you can make your indexPaths to update like `let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows` - method's name is speechful, in case if you have socket I suppose it would be helpful since u've got dynamic